# Aggregation simple code sample - is this correct?

Tags: object-oriented

Please excuse the poor example/analogy, I'm only interested in the code sample.

I have a Dinner_Chair class (inherited from Chair class).  It is as follows.

```
Dinner_Chair = class(Chair)
    Private
      theUser: Person;

    Public
      Dinner_Chair()
      {
            Back = new Back();
            Seat = new Seat();
      }
End
```

I also have a simple Person class, that as you can see, is associated with the Dinner_Chair class.

My question is this. Because the Person class is not instantiated in the Dinner_Chair class, is this an example of aggregation?

This is to consolidate my understanding of **entry level** OOP relationships.

Comment: what programming language is this? I ask because the answers would heavily depend on that: in some languages code like this can simply be blocked by compiler

Comment: ...see also: [Aggregation vs Composition](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61527/31260)

Comment: Also, similar answers over on SO: [What is the difference between aggregation, composition and dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644273/what-is-the-difference-between-aggregation-composition-and-dependency) or [Difference between association, aggregation and composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Comment: yes - the design principle is well documented. However, my question pertains to actual simple implementation of aggregation, and in C#. Post links are useful, but are indirectly addressing question.

Comment: why didn't you use tag [tag:c#]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code terms it *could* be aggregation but not necessarily.   In the real world of dining chairs and people/diners, the relationship isn't aggregation because both objects can exist independently of each other.

The differentiation with regards to the code sample is whether a `Dinner_Chair` is a valid object without a `Person`.

*Aggregation* implies the `Person` is a **required** dependency of `Dinner_Chair` - i.e. `Dinner_Chair` isn't valid without a `Person`.

*Association* implies the `Person` is an **optional** dependency of `Dinner_Chair` - i.e. `Dinner_Chair` is valid without a `Person`.

Comment: Interesting. I missed that 'key' idea you've highlighted! Excellent.    In my code sample, it supposes there must be a person associated with the dinner_chair, that is, upon dinner_chair instantiation. Because I have a separate Person class - and I may instantiate a new Person object at will - I guess this infers that it must be aggregation.  Yes, this is not realistic, but I can see now that the dinner_chair requires a person, before it can be instantiated.